# Alter Adjective order and keep the semantic?

Tags: adjective-order

In phrases/Sentences like:

"They gifted the couple a beautiful porcelain Chinese vase"

where the correct adjectvive order suggest that it would be:

"They gifted the couple a beautiful Chinese porcelain vase"

I think in this particular case, the semantic is not altered, right? I mean they both keep the gist right? Also I don't think it would work in every case of reordering adjectives, some reordering would chance the gist right?

Answer (score 1):

> They gifted the couple a beautiful Chinese porcelain vase.

This version works, so why would we want to switch *Chinese* with *porcelain* and defy grammatical rules? These two adjectives are at number 7 and 8, respectively, as [shown](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order).

1 **opinion** unusual, lovely, beautiful

2 size big, small, tall

3 physical quality thin, rough, untidy

4 shape round, square, rectangular

5 age young, old, youthful

6 colour blue, red, pink

7 **origin** Dutch, Japanese, Turkish

8 **material** metal, wood, plastic

9 type general-purpose, four-sided, U-shaped

10 purpose cleaning, hammering, cooking